# Expanding within a paragraph

Tags: javascript, paragraph, collapsable

I'm fairly new to javascript and I've been playing around with more than 10 stackoverflow solutions to a collapsible paragraph but none of them is true to what I want. Most of them uses lists,buttons,tables css-only(I'm hesitant because browser support issues) . I do not want the link to be any type of buttons , i just want it to be a text link. The expanded sentence should also continue seamlessly and not start on the next line or whatsoever.

What I want is a simple paragraph with a text link inside that once clicked can be expanded. Illustration:
"this is a sentence [more]" -> "this is a sentence and expanded"

And I need it to toggle back when clicked again on the expanded sentence.

Currently I'm using this code but because it deals with divs, I have issues achieving a seamless paragraph. ( I need the expanded text to look like it continues the sentence, not with a break or next line.)

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button-1").click(function(){
      $("#special1").toggle()
})
})
</script>
```

and html

```
<h2>This is a sentence<div id="button-1">[more]</h2>
<p id="special1">blah
blah </p>
</div>
```

and css

```
#special1{ display: none;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check here it is working.**

> I have replaced`<div>`, `<p>` tags with `<span>` because span don't
>   create new line, And in the js i have defined, if message visible then clickable text will be changed to "less" instead of "more". To disable "double-click-text-selection" i have added some css.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button-1").click(function(){
      $("#special1").toggle()
      var isVisible = $( "#special1" ).is( ":visible" );
      if(isVisible){
        $("#button-1").html("[less]");
      }else{
        $("#button-1").html(" [more]");
      }
    
  })
})
```

```css
#special1{ display: none;}
#button-1{
  cursor:pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>

<p>This is a sentence <span id="special1">blah
blah </span><span id="button-1"> [more]</span></p>
```

Comment: since clicking it again changes it to hide...perhaps it should also change from "more" to "less" or "+/-"

Comment: nice, only need to make it so double clicking doesn't selected text. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but the sentence does not continue seamlessly

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that the expanded is in same font style and size ..  I just had to use h2 and p because the previous code I found used p class to target

Comment: I combined your script with user Rocketnuts's script and it worked!

Comment: Edited: Thanks @DaHao to clarify me, Check it now. Are you looking for this?

Comment: how would we add the expanded text into the clickable area for collapsing?

Comment: Are you using any server side language to generate or get full text? That mean is it dynamically generated text ?

Comment: To make **expanded text into the clickable** add `#special1` inside the click selector with comma like: `$("#button-1, #special1").click(function(){`

Comment: hmm I tried adding that but instead now the expansion doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script type='text/javascript'
 src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'>
</script>

<script>
function ShowFull(x)
{
 $('#full').toggle(x);
 $('#short').toggle(!x);
}
</script>
```

```html
This is a sentence <span id='short' onclick='ShowFull(1)'>[more]</span>
<span id='full' onclick='ShowFull(0)' style='display:none'>and expanded.</span>
```

Comment: This is more accurate to what I want but it does not start hidden.
Will adding display: none to #full help?

Comment: it also does not have a toggle back function

Comment: I combined your html with user Ahjeebon's script and it worked!

Comment: @DaHao Oh right, I had this in a test .html where I had `#full { display:none }` in some separate css. I edited my sample above to contain this inline. It does have toggle back though, that should work fine from the start.

Comment: @DaHao Additionally, I would recommend putting `#short, #full { cursor: pointer }` in the accompanying css to give the clickable text a 'link' mouse cursor, indicating that the text is clickable.